# Was the backward-running time stream of the cacogens intended as an allusion to T. H. White's Merlyn?

Tags: time-travel, the-book-of-the-new-sun, the-once-and-future-king

The climax of *The Sword of the Lictor* (and, in many ways, the climax of the entire *Book of the New Sun*) comes in two parts.  There is the battle at Baldanders castle, then the meeting with the visiting aliens who reveal many important facts to Severian—including that he is fated to become the autarch, which they know because (among other reasons) they are moving in the other direction through time.

This inverted temporality is very much like the way Merlyn is portrayed in *The Once and Future King*:

> But I unfortunately was born at the wrong end of Time, and I have to live backwards from in front, while surrounded by a lot of people living forwards from behind.

Merlin is similarly informed about Wart's future as the legendary Arthur from having lived backwards through it already.  It seems as if this parallel cannot have escaped the notice of such a careful writer as Gene Wolfe, and I was wondering whether Wolfe ever indicated that he intended this as a specific allusion to White's earlier work—either merely as a literary device, or perhaps even suggesting that Merlyn was somehow himself akin to the cacogens!

Thinking about this a bit more, it strikes me that there is a further parallel.  Early in Severian's narrative, it seems as if Father Inire is being set up to be revealed as a sinister power behind the autarch's throne.  However, Father Inire turns out to play no direct role in the story at all, and he turns out to be the autarch's loyal (backward-living) advisor—which is just the kind of role that Merlin plays in the story of King Arthur.

So, is there any information about how intentional this was, and how Gene Wolfe intended the similarity to be taken?

Comment: Umm, *no*. It's just that the trio Severian meets is on a kind of trip into past. They live ordinarily, just have a ship that is capable of traveling in time.